# line 23: /etc/init.d/setenv: No such file or directory in linux redhat

Tags: linux, database, redhat, postgresql-9.3, symmetricds

I need to configure SymmtricDS in Linux redhat Machine as Master.I am referring URL to configure in linux.
  http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/2.2/html/advanced-topics.html#running-service-unix

First step is completed

```
cp bin/sym_service.initd /etc/init.d/sym_service
```

next when I run this command

```
[root@samrtcity sbin]# service sym_service start
```

I get the following error.

```
/etc/init.d/sym_service: line 23: /etc/init.d/setenv: No such file or directory
```

The sym_service file is:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Licensed to JumpMind Inc under one or more contributor
# license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed
# with this work for additional information regarding
# copyright ownership.  JumpMind Inc licenses this file
# to you under the GNU General Public License, version 3.0 (GPLv3)
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License,
# version 3.0 (GPLv3) along with this library; if not, see
# <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

. "`dirname "$0"`/setenv"
exec "$SYM_JAVA" -cp "$CLASSPATH" -Djava.io.tmpdir=tmp org.jumpmind.symmetric.wrapper.Wrapper "$1" "$SYM_HOME/opt/SymmtricDS/symmetric-server-3.7.28/symmetric-server-3.7.28/conf/sym_service.conf"
```

but the sym_service.conf file should be there in conf location.

Answer (score -1):

Use the latest version of User Guide with the explanation how to install the [Linux Daemon](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_running_as_a_linux_unix_daemon). The documentation linked in your answer relates to the version 2.2 and from the sym service it seems that you're using the latest version of the library.

Comment: Dear Boris Pavlovic, Thanks for reply,So can you please give me the detailed information for configuring SymmetricDS in Linux 7.1, what is the exact meaning of An init script is written to the system /etc/init.d directory. Symbolic links are created for starting on run levels 2, 3, and 5 and stopping on run levels 0, 1, and 6. To install the script, running the following command as root:

Comment: have you tried running `sudo sh bin/sym_service install`?

Comment: which bin location you are mean, /usr/bin or /opt/SymmtricDS/symmetric-server-3.7.28/symmetric-server-3.7.28/bin

Comment: you're welcome @KarthikKM, an upvote would do the job :)

Comment: Dear Boris Pavlovic,help me out                                                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720927/java-net-malformedurlexception-local-host-name-unknown-java-net-unknownhostexc