# java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: java, linux, database, postgresql, redhat

I need to configure SymmtricDS in Linux redhat Machine as Master.I am referring URL to configure in linux
I installed symmtricDS but when i start the service, using the below command

```
[root@samrtcity bin]# sudo sh sym_service start
```

it will show error like this

```
Waiting for server to start
..
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/SymmtricDS/symmetric-server-3.7.28/symmetric-server-3.7.28/tmp -jar /opt/SymmtricDS/symmetric-server-3.7.28/symmetric-server-3.7.28/lib/symmetric-wrapper.jar exec /opt/SymmtricDS/symmetric-server-3.7.28/symmetric-server-3.7.28/conf/sym_service.conf
    Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: samrtcity.in: samrtcity.in: unknown error
    java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited
            at java.lang.UNIXProcess.exitValue(UNIXProcess.java:424)
            at org.jumpmind.symmetric.wrapper.WrapperService.execJava(WrapperService.java:201)
            at org.jumpmind.symmetric.wrapper.WrapperHelper.run(WrapperHelper.java:32)
            at org.jumpmind.symmetric.wrapper.Wrapper.main(Wrapper.java:48)
    Error 8: Failed second stage
    Native error 8
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: my host file should be like this                                                                127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
xxx.xxx.xx.xx  pluto.cns.utexas.edu
xxx.xxx.xx.xx  smartcity.in

Comment: what's the content of your symmetric-ds.properties file under engines directory?

Comment: you have a typoo in your symmetric-ds.properties file. it should be smartcity.in instead of samrtcity.in